# Synchronise intervall for Facebook for HTC Sense

Tags: sync, facebook, htc-sense

I'm pretty new to the world of Android. Though I managed to solve almost all of upcoming problems on my own, I'm having troubles with this one.

I'd like to increase the number of synchronisations of *HTC Sense* with Facebook so its updates are in line with those of Twitter.

In *Settings* --> *Accounts and Synchronisation* --> *Facebook for HTC Sense* --> *Update Frequency* (the terms might be different; I've got a German UI and translated just on the fly) I can switch between

- every 1, 2, 4, 8, 12 hours
- once a day

On the other hand for *Twitter for HTC Sense*, I've got

- every 5, 15, 30 minutes
- manual

in addition.

As I'm using the *Friend Stream* Widget, I'd like to have the Twitter and Facebook synchronisations of the same frequency.

How can I achieve this? Preferably without installing any additional apps or widgets.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I don't think you can. Those intervals are set by the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Al's right, you can't change the sync frequency for Facebook beyond what they provide.

**Edit:** The below only applies to the regular Facebook app.

But also, all that Facebook syncs is your contacts (and possibly events to the calendar).  It doesn't sync news feed items or notifications, those are only loaded when you actually open the app.  So unless your Facebook friends list changes more often than every hour, syncing more often would be useless.

Comment: In the settings for _Facebook for HTC Sense_ I can select _Synchronise Live-Feed_ **and** _Synchronise Contacts_. In the separate settings for the Facebook App I can only select the contacts and haven't got an option for the frequency.

Comment: @T.K. Oh wow, OK, I had no idea [that app](http://www.htc.com/europe/howto.aspx?id=117&type=1&p_id=313) was completely separate from the regular Facebook app.  It should be theoretically possible to hack the app to check more regularly, but there still isn't an easy method.